# Metadata is also created using "rados put..."command in ceph?

Tags: ceph

I want to know whether metadata is also created using  `rados put {object-name} {file-path} --pool=data` command in ceph?

If not then how metadata can be created and viewed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *omapval* and *xattr* commands of [rados](http://ceph.com/docs/master/man/8/rados/) allow you to attach key/value pairs to the object. They are not included in the content of the object itself, they are metadata. By default there are no *omapval* or *xattr* when you create a new object. Here are a few examples:

```shell
$ rados put FOO /etc/group --pool rbd
$ rados listomapvals FOO --pool rbd
$ rados setomapval FOO frob nitz --pool rbd
$ rados listomapvals FOO --pool rbd
frob
value: (4 bytes) :
0000 : 6e 69 74 7a                                     : nitz

$ rados listxattr FOO --pool rbd
$ rados setxattr FOO fi bou --pool rbd
$ rados listxattr FOO --pool rbd
fi
$ rados getxattr FOO fi --pool rbd
bou
```

Comment: ok. but I also have an another questions.that what is use of metadata server if we can directly interact with osd and retrive objects from there?and when we use "rm object" command, it deletes only object or metadata also?